# Vocabulary learning on linux using Free Dictionary files (TEI P5 XML)

Tags: language-support, xml, training

for brushing up a foreign language, I need to find a way to use Free Dictionary files in TEI P5 xml format with one of the vocabulary trainers available for Linux. So far I tried Parley, Pauker and Multi-Language-Vocabulary-Trainer, but it seems none of those is able to use/import/convert the TEI P5 XML format. 
Is there any way to convert the TEI XML to something one of those above can use? Or is there a trainer I didn't find yet that supports the TEI format?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try `Anki`? It's available in the repository.